# Применение запятой

Tags: пунктуация

*Не знаете с чего начать подготовку к свадьбе? Все ответы тут!* (заголовок к статье)

Нужна ли запятая после "не знаете"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 8):

Нужна! Она разделяет главное предложение и придаточное. ***Не знаете, с чего начать подготовку к свадьбе?***